# DBD::JDBC with POstgres

Tags: postgresql, perl, jdbc

Here is my problem, my code is simple connect to the database execute a query and retrieve some row

I can connect to the database but the problem is when I want to execute a query 
here is the code

```
my $url = "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x\\db";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:JDBC:hostname=localhost;port=$opt_P;url=$url",
    test, xxx, {RaiseError => 4, PrintError => 4});

$query = "SELECT setting FROM pg_catalog.pg_settings
          WHERE name = 'server_version'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare ($query) or die "prepare failed\n";
print "Got here without dying2\n";
$sth->execute( ) or die "unable to execute query $query   error $DBI::errstr";`
```

and I got this error

> DBD::JDBC::st execute warning: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING" Position: 74 at ./test

Strange thing it's working with dbi:odbc and jdbc is working with java and postgresql but not perl :(

Comment: Is that the correct code? Looks like that error was generated by running a completely different query.

Comment: I didn't put all the variables init and others things, because you dont 's see "Got here without dying2" ?

Answer (score 1):

problem solved with this version JDBC42 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.4.1211